# mod_rewrite not working on VPS with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

So after moving from shared host to VPS my mod_rewrite stopped working.
I turned on mod_rewrite in my apache, but still nothing.

[image: 1st image]
[image: 2nd image]

all my project files are stored in `/var/www/html/project` and my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /html/project/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?)/{2,}([^\s]*)
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2 [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(.+?)/{2,}[?\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}  [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} system|application
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

but mod_rewrite don't want to work. I'm using digitalocean VPS. Any ideas? Btw VPS installed apache details: Ubuntu LAMP on 14.04 and I'm using codeigniter for my project

Comment: Did you setup your `virtualhost` file?

Answer (score 2):

So after some time I've discovered that I've to change `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` as well as other files. I have enabled multiviews http://prntscr.com/6qt89p

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying .htaccess without RewriteBase. Change **AllowOverride FileInfo** to **AllowOverride all** in file /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default

```
Options -Indexes +MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /html/project/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?)/{2,}([^\s]*)
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2 [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(.+?)/{2,}[?\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}  [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} system|application
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```